# How to set up UIBezierPath border for view in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I created `CAShapeLayer` border for view using the below code:

```
func addBorderToWebView() {
    borderShape = CAShapeLayer()
    borderShape.path = UIBezierPath(rect: webView.frame).cgPath
    borderShape.lineWidth = CGFloat(2)
    borderShape.bounds = borderShape.path!.boundingBox
    borderShape.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 68/255, green: 219/255, blue: 94/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    borderShape.position = CGPoint(x: borderShape.bounds.width/2, y: borderShape.bounds.height/2)
    webView.layer.addSublayer(borderShape)
}
```

I right and bottom border lines are out of the frame, you can see it on the image below. However, if I define `borderWidth` property of `webView.layer`, everything appears to be showed fine. That is why I make a conclusion, that the problem is not in layout constraints. How should I configure `UIBezierPath` (or `CAShapeLayer`) to make the border be showed correctly? Thank you for any help!

[image: CAShapeLayer border]

Comment: How is `htmlPreviewer` related to `webView` in terms of view hierarchy? Where do you call `addBorderToWebView` method?

Comment: @alexburtnik Oh, sorry, I renamed `htmlPreviewer` to `webView` for the question just to make it more  clear. Forgot to rename this one. Fixed it!

Comment: Ok, so where do you call this method?

Comment: Try calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` right before doing `addBorderToWebView()`. The thing is I've tried your code and it works fine with a fullscreen webview.

Comment: To make sure if it's a layout issue or not you can print webView's frame when your method gets called. I guess it's bigger than you expect (probably 1000*1000)

Comment: @alexburtnik you were right about the frame. However, even after calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()`, the bottom  line isn't showing up. I guess the issue could be related with the tab bar. Also I don't understand why in this conditions setting borderWidth makes border appear in a right way. The content showed in the webView is showed correctly too.

Comment: Can you please show how and where do you set `borderWidth`, which fixes the issue?

Comment: @alexburtnik `borderWidth` is set the following way `self.webView.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(2)`, right after `viewDidLoad()` is finished

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125856/discussion-between-alexburtnik-and-d3migod).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this

```
borderShape.path = UIBezierPath(rect: webView.frame).cgPath
```

with this:

```
borderShape.path = UIBezierPath(rect: webView.bounds).cgPath
```

Another possible cause of the problem is that `webView`'s frame is not updated yet when you set it to `borderShape`. You can try to do `self.view.updateLayoutIfNeeded()` prior to adding border shape. If it doesn't help override the following method:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    updateBorderShape()
}

func updateBorderShape() {
    borderShape.bounds = webView.bounds
    borderShape.position = CGPoint(x: borderShape.bounds.width/2, y: borderShape.bounds.height/2)
}
```

This will make sure that every time your frames are updated, border shape is updated as well.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, it should fix the issue.